# The two problems in the image cannot be placed in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

[image]

```
$\left(x+a\right)^{2}+2ax+a^{2}$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what exactly it is that you're trying to accomplish. (Remark: The wording of the title is *not* clear at present.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? At least you should write equation that we don't need to write it from scratch. What you looking for, can be done by use of the `tikzmark` library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\[
(x + \tikzmarknode{A}{a})^2 = x^2 + 2\tikzmarknode{B}{a}x + \tikzmarknode{C}{a}^2
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,shorten <=1mm,
                    shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm]
\draw[->] (A.south) -- ++ (0,-0.5) -| node[pos=0.25, fill=white] {text} (B.south);
\draw[->] (A.south) -- ++ (0,-1.0) -| node[pos=0.25, fill=white] {text} (C.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{3ex}    % space for image
\]
\end{document}
```

Note: For correct result you need to compile document at least two times, typically three times.